# Нужен ли вопросительный знак?

Tags: пунктуация

"Разве мог я тогда предвидеть, к чему это приведёт?" или без вопросительного знака: "Разве мог я тогда предвидеть, к чему это приведёт"? С одной стороны, похоже на вопрос, но я видел много таких предложений без вопросительного знака в конце.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) **Согласно правилу, возможны три варианта оформления:** вопросительный знак, восклицательный знак, два знака.

Розенталь:

[§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания  »»   Вопросительный знак — восклицательный знак](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=194#pp194)

В зависимости от оттенка значения и от интонации некоторые предложения могут иметь на конце либо вопросительный, либо восклицательный знак: Да разве можно такими речами поносить родителей? (Остр.) — возможна постановка восклицательного знака; Откуда у меня деньгам быть! (Л. Т.) — возможна постановка вопросительного знака.
Отсюда появляется возможность постановки обоих знаков; ср.:
**Неужели вы не знаете таких простых вещей? Неужели вы не знаете таких простых вещей! Неужели вы не знаете таких простых вещей?!**

**2) [Риторический вопрос | ru.wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)**

Ритори́ческий вопро́с — риторическая фигура, представляющая собой вопрос-утверждение, который не требует ответа.

По сути, риторический вопрос — это вопрос, ответ на который не требуется или не ожидается в силу его крайней очевидности для говорящего. В любом случае вопросительное высказывание подразумевает вполне определённый, всем известный ответ, так что риторический вопрос, фактически, представляет собой утверждение, высказанное **в вопросительной форме.**

**3) Вопросительная форма риторического вопроса**

Форма - это грамматика и интонация. С точки зрения грамматики, предложение строится как вопросительное, но при этом может иметь три вида интонации: вопросительная (повышение голоса  конце предложения), восклицательная (усиленное  фразовое ударение без повышения голоса в конце предложения) и сочетание этих вариантов.

4) **Вывод:** 1) выбираем одну из трех форм; 2) об отсутствии знаков (простая повествовательная интонация) в правиле не говорится.

Answer (score 0):

> *Разве мог я тогда предвидеть, к чему это приведёт?*
>
> *Разве мог я тогда предвидеть, к чему это приведёт.*

.

Верен первый вариант. См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)

> **§ 1… Вопросительный знак ставится также в конце вопроса, если он риторический**:
>
> *Кто скажет что-нибудь в защиту зависти? Это чувство дрянной категории* (Булг.).

Answer (score 0):

В конце риторического вопроса ставится вопросительный или восклицательный знак. ([Знаки препинания в конце предложения | svetozar.ru](http://www.svetozar.ru/book/pr_end.shtml))

Вопросительный знак:

Кто не проклинал станционных смотрителей, кто с ними не бранивался? 
А. Пушкин «Станционный смотритель»

Восклицательный знак:

Да разве найдутся на свете такие огни, муки и такая сила, которая бы пересилила русскую силу! 
Н. Гоголь «Тарас Бульба»

Я совсем забыл, что вышел в сандалиях, что с собой у меня нет и корочки хлеба. Да разве можно тут помнить! Прямо, как есть, я спешу, почти что бегу в Ляхово болото за восемь вёрст. [М. М. Пришвин. Кэт (1925)]

Comment: _М_Г: "восклицательный знак... Гоголь"_  === А что современные-то правила говорят?

Comment: @slava1947: Если найдете такое правило, которое **обязывает** ставить вопросительный знак - поделитесь. А пока –  еще пример с восклицательным (более современный): Я совсем забыл, что вышел в сандалиях, что с собой у меня нет и корочки хлеба. Да разве можно тут помнить! Прямо, как есть, я спешу, почти что бегу в Ляхово болото за восемь вёрст. [М. М. Пришвин. Кэт (1925)]

Answer (score 0):

Я учился в советской школе, и учитель нам говорил, что обозначение риторического вопроса такое: "?!"

В конце предложения, учитывая тот факт, что в литературе риторический вопрос обладает восклицанием и при произношение создаёт приподнятый оттенок в речи, то, мне кажется, это логично — отмечать так.