# Постановка знаков препинания: Хвалы приманчивы () как их не пожелать ()

Tags: запятые, тире, бессоюзное

Как  расставить знаки препинания в известном афоризме Крылова?

***Хвалы приманчивы, какъ ихъ не пожелать.*** Крыловъ.

В современном тексте басни используются и другие знаки, но как их правильно выбрать и обосновать? Чем различаются варианты, какой из них наиболее удачен? И какой вариант был вначале, почему он исправлен?

***Хвалы приманчивы, — как их не пожелать!***

***Хвалы приманчивы; как их не пожелать?***

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1) У Розенталя стоит тире, вроде бы самый подходящий знак для БСП. **А откуда взялся двойной знак**, как его объяснить? Кажется, он чаще других встречается.

2) **Можно поставить запятую вместо тире**, это соответствует правилам?

3) **А точку с запятой как объяснить?** Мне кажется, она совершенно здесь не подходит, кто ее поставил?

4) **Это риторический вопрос?**

У Розенталя стоит вопросительный знак, выглядит логично. Два знака здесь вряд ли пойдут.

А если поставить только восклицательный знак? Или для этого нужна особая структура (**разве** можно их не пожелать!)?

И можно ли поставить точку, то есть не оформлять риторический вопрос вообще?

[Нужен ли вопросительный знак?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430044/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA)

Comment: Удивительно! Гуглится около десятка разных вариантов пунктуации и не только в современных источниках. Замечу, что Розенталь в "Трудных случаях пунктуации" (и в нескольких других книгах) настаивает на варианте с тире и вопросительным знаком. Такую же пунктуацию отстаивает Виноградов в "Вопросах синтаксиса современного русского языка", а также многие авторы учебных пособий для школьников. Но в те же годы выходят ПСС и другие добротные издания с отличными вариантами пунктуации.

Comment: И я не задумываясь поставил бы тире и вопросительный знак (двойной знак с восклицательным хуже, поскольку это оценка мотива со стороны), без запятых. Точка с запятой без надобности _разделяет_ смыслы - проще было бы точку поставить.

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума! Пожалуйста, оформите свои комментарии как ответы, а то  так сложно общаться. И это будет по правилам. Пожалуйста... А  я немного дополню тему конкретными вопросами.